# Grails application while debugging throws Exception

Tags: grails

I am new to grails and trying to debug my application.
I am getting following error when I try to debug my application, however it is running fine in normal mode. I couldn't figure out what's wrong from error description. Am I missing something?

```
Error 2013-05-28 15:59:13,903 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException
Message: org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException
```

BootStrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication;
    def atomUtil;

    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.config.dpc.currentTimestamp = DateUtil.getCurrentDateMidnight(); // yesterday

        // check the env only if in development mode
        if (Environment.getCurrent().name != "development"
        || "${System.env['SCST_CONFIG_load_reference_data']}" == "true") {
            def atomThread = Thread.start {
                AtomInfo.withTransaction { status ->
                    atomUtil.initializeData();
                }
            }
            def contextThread = Thread.start {
                ContextInfo.withTransaction { status ->
                    ContextUtil.initializeData();
                }
            }
            atomThread.join()
            contextThread.join()
        } else {
            log.info "[env:${Environment.getCurrent().name}] Skipping ATOMS & CONTEXTS Load. In development, set environmental SCST_CONFIG_load_reference_data=true"
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in `Bootstrap`. Can you show `Bootstrap.groovy`?

Comment: look at my edit above..thanks for your interest

Comment: What is `ContextUtil` and where is it defined/injected?

Answer (score 0):

Try organize imports and refresh dependencies.

Comment: and how would I do that? Could you be more specific, I m sorry, it's all new for me

Comment: Import your project in GGTS or STS http://grails.org/products/ggts. Right click on your project > Grails > refresh dependencies. Open Bootstrap.groovy do organize import: on MAC cmd + Shift + o, Win: cmd replaced by alt or strg

Comment: Thanks confile, Tried everything you said ..still getting same error!

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace: grails run-app --stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I was using Grails 2.1.0 and had this error.

When I upgraded to 2.1.5 I no longer had the error. I also upgraded GGTS to 3.6